# How to add sorting to my controller? [Spring Boot, Thymeleaf]

Tags: spring-boot, sorting, thymeleaf

How do I add a sorting parameter? Right now, the data is only sorted by one aspect, and I want to be able to choose from many different options, like ASC id, ASC/DESC name, email etc.

After that I need to modify my thymeleaf template to display the options.

```
   @GetMapping("/users") 
   public String showPage(Model model, @RequestParam(defaultValue="0") int page) {
       model.addAttribute("data", userRepo.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, 30, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id"))));
       model.addAttribute("currentPage", page);
       model.addAttribute("totalElement", userRepo.count());
       return "users"; 
   }
```

I really don't know how to do it, I'd apprectiate it very much if you'd be able to help. I'm still new to Spring Boot so please keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Add request params that indicate sorting direction and a sorting field?

```
@GetMapping("/users") 
public String showPage(Model model, @RequestParam(defaultValue="0") int page, @RequestParam(default = "desc") String sortDirection, @RequestParam(default = "id") String sortBy) {
    model.addAttribute("data", userRepo.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, 30, Sort.by(sortDirection.equals("desc") ? Sort.Direction.DESC : Sort.Direction.ASC, sortBy))));
    model.addAttribute("currentPage", page);
    model.addAttribute("totalElement", userRepo.count());
    return "users"; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! And how do I do it in my template? How can i create a button for switching?

Comment: For the beginning, you can simply generate URLs that contain appropriate sorting direction and sorting property parameters.